# Understanding overloads of GroupBy in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

i was going through linq GroupBy extension method and stumbled on one of the overloads which got me confused, now this will yield an result like this

```
 int[] numbers = {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5 };
            var result = numbers.GroupBy(g => g).Select(s => new {
                key=s.Key,
                data=s
            });
```

[image]

but my question is, how to use other overloads, for instance this

[image]

how can i use this overload, i have searched many blogs but no blogs explain me all the overloads

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: The documentation *does* explain what each overload does. You can save a *lot * of time if you check the docs before googling for blog posts. In your case it's [GroupBy(Func,Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx). If you had objects with properties instead of integers, you could use the element selector to return a single property or calculated value instead of the entire object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The docs is useful as a reference. It is a technical explanation with a lot of jargon. If you don't understand the purpose/jargon at all, this explanation will also be difficult to understand. For a higher level overview, blogs can be more helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `elementSelector` lets you *project* the *elements* (your numbers).

```
int[] numbers = {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5 };
var result = numbers.GroupBy(g => g, i => 2 * i); // project each number to the doubled value
```

resulting in

```
3 times 2    (2 * 1)
2 times 4    (2 * 2)
1 time  6    (2 * 3)
5 times 8    (2 * 4)
2 times 10   (2 * 5)
```

I personally prefer the overload taking a `resultSelector` over the extra call to `Select`:

```
int[] numbers = {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5 };
var result = numbers.GroupBy(g => g, (key, g) => new {
    key,
    data=g
 });
```

The `resultSelector` is equivalent to the subsequent `Select` call in your example, but it takes the key and the sequence of elemetns for that key as separate parameters, while `Select` works on the resulting `IGrouping<>`.

Comment: @IvanStoev fixed it, just missed that the `resultSelector` needs the key _and_ the sequence of elements for this key as parameters.